# Using Database storage for uses other than offline apps

Tags: javascript, sql, sqlite, html, offlineapps

I've been looking into offline database storage with HTML5 and the built in Sqlite Db. I think it has a potential for things other than just storing data for offline apps.

What I'm interested in, is hearing about potential uses of the database for storing things other than offline web page content. What has anyone in the commnity been using it for, other than offline applications? What are the security and performance considerations?

I'm thinking of things like distributed computing, like the project on the playstation a while back that used its idle time etc. Could this model work with browsers for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes there is. check out [Project Legion](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/gridcomputing.aspx) which is a virtual super computer with Silverlight.